# Use of square brackets in objects

Tags: javascript, brackets

my code *has* to be like this:

```
rules: {
  jform[name]: {
  required:true,
  minlength:5,
  maxlength:15
},
```

how should I use those square brackets? There are a lot of answers regarding this subject found on this website and on google, but not particularly for this one.

Comment: Your code *can't* be like that. That's invalid JavaScript. How are you **actually** trying to access the object?

Comment: I've removed all other code around it, I just need to know how I can use the [] around 'name'. Is that not possible?

Comment: Have you tried backslashes? ( `\[` or `\\[` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the value of `jform[name]` to a key in the object.  You can't use variables as keys when declaring an object literal.  You'll have to add this key as another statement.

Example:

```
var data = {
    rules: {
    }
};
data.rules[jform[name]]= {
    required:true,
     minlength:5,
     maxlength:15
};
```

If you want the key to literally be `jform[name]`, then you need to use quotes around the key.

```
rules: {
    "jform[name]": {
        required:true,
        minlength:5,
        maxlength:15
    }
}
```

Comment: so simple! This was all there is to it: "jform[name]" Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 7):

I can't accurately answer your question as it stands right now, because you're asking how to use invalid syntax, which is impossible as it's invalid.

However, what I *can* do is explain how JSON works in JavaScript and hope that it covers your problem:

### The basics

#### `{}` is an object literal

```
//this creates a new object
a = {};
//so does this
a = new Object();
```

#### `[]` is an array literal

```
//this creates a new array
a = [];
//so does this
a = new Array();
```

#### properties can be accessed via `.` and `[]` notation:

```
//these are the same
a.b = c;
a['b'] = c;
```

#### Object literals can be set using literal values or strings:

```
a = {
    //any character you can use for a variable name can be
    //used to instantiate an object without quotes
    b: c,
    //special characters need to be quoted
    "foo bar baz": "fizz buzz"
};
```

---

Your original syntax of:

```
rules: {
  jform[name]: {
  required:true,
  minlength:5,
  maxlength:15
}
```

is invalid because you can't use `[` and `]` chars in a variable name, however you could use a string for the literal value:

```
rules: {
  "jform[name]": {
  required:true,
  minlength:5,
  maxlength:15
}
```

...which would be accessed as:

```
rules["jform[name]"]
```

but it appears that you want to access the data as:

```
rules.jform[name]
```

which would need to be set as:

```
rules: {
    jform: {}
}
...more code...
rules.jform[name] = {rules: {
    required:true,
    minlength:5,
    maxlength:15
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
obj = {
 "rules" : {
  "jform" : {
    "name" : {
      required:true,
      minlength:5,
      maxlength:15
    }
   }
  }
},
```

you can now access values like this

```
 obj[rules][jform][name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean JSON? Or JavaScript Object literals? Please remove the buzzword "jQuery" from your question.

If you want a property name with (square) brackets, you can either do

```
rules = {
  "jform[name]": {
    required:true,
    minlength:5,
    maxlength:15
  }
}
```

or

```
rules["jform[name]"] = {...};
```